# Moment.js is not showing right time

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm getting wrong time from momentjs when I pass UTC date time I expect it to convert to 7:30pm in Melbourne

Ex:

```
var myUTCTime = moment("2020-12-02 09:30:00.0000000 +00:00").utc();
```

**Wed Dec 02 2020 09:30:00 GMT+0000**

```
var melbourne = moment("2020-12-02 09:30:00.0000000 +00:00").utc().tz("Australia/Melbourne");
```

**Wed Dec 02 2020 20:30:00 GMT+1100**

Expecting Melbourne to be Wed Dec 02 2020 19:30:00 GMT+1000

7:30 PM (19:30) Melbourne Time = 9:30 AM (9:30) UTC

Following url shows the graph

http://www.timebie.com/timezone/universalmelbourne.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's taking **Daylight Savings** into account (observed in month of December).

For other dates, it's just fine. I tried May.

```js
moment("2020-05-02 09:30:00.000 +00:00").utc().toString()
"Sat May 02 2020 09:30:00 GMT+0000"

moment("2020-05-02 09:30:00.000 +00:00").utc().tz("Australia/Melbourne").toString(); 
"Sat May 02 2020 19:30:00 GMT+1000"
```